# JButton text not changing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

So my code basically has a `JPanel` with some text fields and a `JButton`, and when the user clicks the button it goes to the button listener, which then takes the data from the text fields and processes it, creating `JLabels` which it adds to another invisible `JPanel`. I then make the first JPanel invisible, and make the second panel visible, revealing the "results" I generate.

This all works but the problem is, while my program processes the data it gets from the text fields, I want the `JButton` to change what it says, and I already tried using `event.getSource().setText()`, and I was able to find that it is changing the button text (by printing to the console), but it is not updating the button with the changed text.

I tried all forms of revalidate and repaint and validate as well after this, but none of it worked. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
//entryPanel is the first panel, and picksPanel is the second panel
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                           {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    ((JButton)event.getSource()).setText("Thinking...");
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    try
    {    
      CriticPick picks = new CriticPick(cityfield.getText(),statefield.getText());
      LinkedList<Movie> pickslist = picks.getList();
      glayout.setRows(pickslist.size()+2+thepicks.movnum);
      picksPanel.add(new JLabel("The Results:"));

      //In my actual code I do a bunch of processing and looping that results in jlabels being added to picksPanel
      for (int i=0;i<pickslist.size();i++)
      {
          JLabel label = new JLabel(pickslist.get(i).title);
          picksPanel.add(label);
      }  
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      System.out.println(exc);
    }

    entryPanel.setVisible(false);
    picksPanel.setVisible(true);

  }});

  guiFrame.add(entryPanel);
  guiFrame.add(picksPanel);
  guiFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
  guiFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I hope you not performing a long running task, which is blocking the EDT for necessary updates... Why not use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this scenario, instead of pulling your hair with `revalidate()/repaint()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that no paint event is processed before your job is completed, so the effect of the `setText` won't show when you think it will.

`repaint()` only promises to repaint "as soon as possible" (per the docs), but since paint events are processed on the same thread as button click events (the "Event Dispatch Thread"), your processing effectively causes the `setText` call and panel hiding/showing to occur at the same time (so to speak), *after* the job is done.

The effect of blocking the EDT with data crunching jobs is obvious if your job takes a noticeable amount of time - the UI will become completely unresponsive since the EDT doesn't have any opportunity to repaint, process resize/mouse click events, etc.

Heavy processing should be done in background threads, preferrably by the aid of a `SwingWorker`. This leaves the EDT free to handle paint (and other) events.